# Can I delete my public GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I have a Git repository hosted publicly on GitHub that I would like to delete. How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVrZ5rABuxM

Answer (score 26):

See [Deleting a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository), from **Help.GitHub**.

> 1. Go to the repo's Settings page
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click "Delete this repository"
> 3. Read the warnings and enter the name of the repository you want to delete
> 4. Click "I understand the consequences, delete this repository"

Deleting a public repo will leave the forks, but if it was private, then all its forks would also be deleted.

Comment: The links given above <strike>[Deleting a repo](http://help.github.com/deleting-a-repo/)</strike> says you can not use this to delete a public repository! -----
**EDIT:** The first link is appeared to be broken. Use the following link: [Deleting a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository)

Comment: @godlinbox _Deleting a private repo will delete all forks of the repo. Deleting a public repo will not._

Comment: It says forks (copies, more or less) of your repository by other users won't be deleted, your own repository will. Note the difference.

Comment: The "admin" page is now called "Settings" page.

Answer (score 5):

Yes absolutely, please follow the steps

1. Login to your account
2. Click on Repositories
3. Select your Repository (that you wants to delete)
4. Click on settings tab
5. Goto "Danger Zone" block
6. Click on "Delete this repository" button
7. Type the repository name (that you wants to delete)
8. Now click "I understand the consequences, delete this repository" button
9. Now your repository deleted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install hub: https://github.com/github/hub
2. `hub delete <repo_name>`

Hub will ask for your username and password at the first use. It then creates an api token for later usage. You need to grant hub the right to delete your repos with this token in your github settings (only required to be done once).

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier than what recommended before. Check this link from the Github Help page, they tell you to go the settings inside your repository and then to the danger zone, then you click delete this repository and confirm that by typing your password.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/deleting-a-repository